# AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT won’t work on MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, aes, mysql-5.7

When I run the following code I simply get NULL for both outputs. I have also tried using `unhex()` around the first decryption argument, but still the same result.

```
SELECT @encrypt = AES_ENCRYPT('hello', 'key');

SELECT @decrypt = AES_DECRYPT(@encrypt, 'key');
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `:` operator

query should be :

```
SELECT @encrypt := AES_ENCRYPT('hello', 'key');

SELECT @decrypt := AES_DECRYPT(@encrypt, 'key');
```

For the detailed explanation, read the [mysql documentation for user defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html).

While we are at it, AES_ENCRYPT and AES_DECRYPT return binary string in hexadecimal format. So if you want to get string value, cast it as char:

```
SELECT @encrypt := CAST(AES_ENCRYPT('hello', 'key') AS CHAR);

SELECT @decrypt := CAST(AES_DECRYPT(@encrypt, 'key') AS CHAR);
```

Comment: Because `aes_encrypt` return (binary) string in hexadecimal format. So you should cast it as char. For more in depth heres the documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html